# Need help understanding the approach to this question

Tags: descriptive-statistics

At a meeting of information systems officers for regional offices of a national company, a survey was taken to determine the number of employees the officers supervise in the operation of their departments, where X is the number of employees overseen by each information systems officer and f  is the frequency.

```
X   f   
1   7
2   5
3   11
4   8
5   9
```

a) Referring to the table, how many regional offices are represented in the survey results?

Comment: Just multiply the numbers in the rows (e.g. 1*7,2*5,...) and add up all the numbers you get.

Comment: This gives the total number of employees not the number of offices.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the sum of the f-column. 7 information systems officers are overseeing only 1 employee, 5 are overseeing 2 employees, etc.

So the total number of information system officers in this survey is the sum of the f-column, or 40.